# TypeScript with Angular.JS and web API

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angularjs, typescript, asp.net-web-api

I'm working on an asp.mvc3 web api project. in this project I use TypeScript and Angular.js
and I need to access the business layer from TypeScript through the Web API. I called the Web API inside the constructor method in TypeScript using the 
code given below.

```
constructor($scope, $http: any) {
    $scope.VM = this;
    $http.get("/API/PrivateAPI/Test/1").success((a) => { this.Tiles = a });
    var bb = this.Tiles;
}
```

However, when trying to get the object list from the business layer, the `Tiles` array is empty. I debugged the code and found out the Web API is called after passing the last line of the constructor and does return results. I need to call that method inside the constructor and get object list to the Tiles array.

Does anyone know how to do so?

Comment: Does this typescript (a) => translate into function(a)? because that's what success will be expecting (a function with an argument that it will pass the resolved data to)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of, I think you should do the following (notice `.data`) :

```
$http.get("/API/PrivateAPI/Test/1").success((response) => { this.Tiles = response.data });
```

Anyways, $http only supports async http requests. What you want can be done by a synchronous XHR request and that is considered bad UI experience, since the browser window freezes till the XHR request completes, and therefore $http doesn't support it ([configuration docs](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24http#Parameters)).

What you can do is something like :

1. call another function from response e.g.

   ```
   (response) => { this.Tiles = response.data; this.continueWithProcessing(); }
   ```
2. Or, Setup a variable to hide a preloader when the response comes back:

   ```
   (response) => { this.Tiles = response.data; this.allDone=true; }
   ```

   Where you have an ng-show on something like:

   ```
   <div ng-show="!VM.allDone">Loading the data....</div>
   ```

Or both :)

**Note:** An async setting is supported in underlying browsers native XHR object and therefore in $.ajax which is the jquery ajax function : http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#jQuery-ajax-settings. However it is a horrible UI experience + if you use it from angular you are responsible for `scope.apply`.

Comment: Hi @BASarat, i tried what you mentioned above. but it doesn't works. Actually i need to  get the object list from business layer  that i mentioned about and  add new properties in the typescript layer and pass it again to view. in another words get business model from business layer and convert it to view model with new properties and pass that view modal to view. this is the scenario which i want. can you help me to solve this problem?